# OpenID in new SPA MVC 4 App throwing VerficationException - Operation could destabilize the runtime

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, openid, intellitrace, verificationexception

Starting with an new project via SPA template.   Followed cookbook to use Google OpenID.   The UI now shows a button with a link to Google...   Clicking the link the call to VerfiyAuthentication throws an verificationexception.  Operation could destabilize the runtime.

Searching for this exception has lead me to a lot of different dead ends.

==============================  From the asp.net error =================================

Operation could destabilize the runtime.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Security.VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime.

Source Error:

Line 226:      public ActionResult ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
Line 227:      {
Line 228:         AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
Line 229:         if (!result.IsSuccessful)
Line 230:         {

Source File: c:\Users\weidson\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MvcApplication5\MvcApplication5\Controllers\AccountController.cs    Line: 228

Stack Trace:

[VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime.]
   DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Messages.IndirectSignedResponse.GetSignedMessageParts(Channel channel) +991
   DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ExtensionsBindingElement.GetExtensionsDictionary(IProtocolMessage message, Boolean ignoreUnsigned) +313
   DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.d__a.MoveNext() +274
   DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ExtensionsBindingElement.ProcessIncomingMessage(IProtocolMessage message) +598
   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.ProcessIncomingMessage(IProtocolMessage message) +1119
   DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.OpenIdChannel.ProcessIncomingMessage(IProtocolMessage message) +398
   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.ReadFromRequest(HttpRequestBase httpRequest) +705
   DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.OpenIdRelyingParty.GetResponse(HttpRequestBase httpRequestInfo) +299
   DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.OpenIdRelyingParty.GetResponse() +379
   DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.Clients.OpenIdClient.VerifyAuthentication(HttpContextBase context) +183
   DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.OpenAuthSecurityManager.VerifyAuthentication(String returnUrl) +1243
   Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth.OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthenticationCore(HttpContextBase context, String returnUrl) +174
   Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth.OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(String returnUrl) +139
   MvcApplication5.Controllers.AccountController.ExternalLoginCallback(String returnUrl) in c:\Users\weidson\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MvcApplication5\MvcApplication5\Controllers\AccountController.cs:228
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +181
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +437
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41() +75
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.b__7(IAsyncResult *) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +140
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33() +126
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +323
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +323
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +140
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass2a.b_*20() +68
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass25.b_*22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +184
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +137
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +152
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +152
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +152
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +930
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +188

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer.  Turning Intellitrace off allows this to work.   Looks like a timing issue when using that form of debugger.

Comment: Has anyone seen other odd behaviour when using intellitrace?